# Unity ARKit - make materials NOT affected by world light?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, light

Ok, so I have through all of Unity's UnityARKitLightManager from ARKit and I am trying to figure out to how ensure that the gameobjects I place in AR are NOT affected by real world lighting - that their materials (diffuse) remain bright/only affected by lights in my scene.

In don't know how ARKit is affecting materials as I can't find it - what I've is just made sure their Light array does not get my lights:

```
    //or just dont let my lights get in here
    Light []  FindAllLights()
    {
//      return FindObjectsOfType<Light> ();
        return new Light[0];
    }
```

Then in `UpdateLightEstimations` which we need for tracking, Im not seeing anything to do with my actual gameobjects. Yet they are still dark despite diffuse textures - am I missing something?